# iRedMail NginX config file update

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

Referring the guides [Using iRedMail with NginX](http://blog.eridlabs.com/using-iredmail-with-nginx-ubuntu-13-04-x64/) and [Setting up iRedMail with NginX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974056/setup-iredmail-admin-site-in-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04/22490727#22490727), I'd like to ask that in the server block

> server {
>       listen      80;
>       server_name mail.mydomain.com;

```
location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/apache2$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

I want to just remove the /usr/share/apache2 directory using
`$ sudo apt-get remove apache2`
or
`$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/apache2`

therefore in the NginX iRedMail config, can I replace the following line
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/apache2$fastcgi_script_name;`
with
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx$fastcgi_script_name;`
or with
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /etc/nginx$fastcgi_script_name; #I can see a file named fastcgi_params at /etc/nginx/`

Secondly, I'd be interested in knowing how does the variable $fastcgi_script_name gets resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how the variable $fastcgi_script_name gets resolved.
According to my understanding, it basically replaces it with the value of $fastcgi_index, which in turn is index.php in the above case.
The recommended line is:
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

However, for that it needs to have the root variable defined either inside the location {} scope or the outer server {} scope.
Since, it is not defined in either of the above mentioned server block therefore for the time being I'm going to stick to:
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;`